# Why is "Warning: Implicit string type conversion from AnsiString to UnicodeString" here while both are Strings?

Tags: freepascal

Here I get an warning `Warning: Implicit string type conversion from "AnsiString" to "UnicodeString"`

```pascal
....
{$mode DelphiUnicode}
{$H+}
....

Function THeader.ToHtml(Constref input: String): String;
Begin
  Result := Format('<h%d>%s</h%d>', [FLevel, Chunk(input), FLevel]);   // <--- HERE !
End;
```

My project settings include `-MDelphiUnicode`. My Lazarus version is 2.2.2.

As I understand it means that if `Chunk()` returns symbols outside of ASCII (Unicode), then the `Result` will be problematic. Right? What to do with this warning? Sure, I can cast the `Format()` result to `String`. But why is it required? I see that `Format`'s prototype is:

```pascal
// somewhere in the sysstrh.inc ...
Function Format (Const Fmt : String; const Args : Array of const) : String;
```

so it already returns a `String` (which is magically `UnicodeString` in my case, as I think). What is the problem actually here? And how to work in the correct way with such library functions like `Format()` (for instance, `GetOptionValue()` of `TCustomApplication`)?

ps. I read FreePascal Wiki about Unicode and String types, but I still cannot understand the reason of this warning :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple reasons to do so.

The exact codepage of ansistring is under control of the RTL, which can query the OS for it, without the compiler knowing the details. In Lazarus applications this is generally set to utf8, but the compiler doesn't know that.

So calling a ansistring format() could corrupt strings, and repeated conversions are of course also not ideal for a performance.

delphiunicode is a work in progress, and I would not recommend using it  (yet) out of habit, only if you really know what you are doing (and by that I mean knowing the state of it in FPC, not that it works in Delphi)

The original plan was to migrate to unicodestring fully, but since Windows now allows UTF8 as native 1-byte codepage (see thick in application tab of project options), the progress on that migration is glacial.

In short, consider arranging your code as much as possible so that string type doesn't matter, and then use utf8 ansistrings in Lazarus for unicode.

Or ignore the warnings, or disable them with some -vn parameter that allows you to disable specific hints/warnings